# Delete Task from ListView Using ActionBar Menu Button Android

Tags: android

I am working on a an application designed for students. In this application I have a list view that contains student task stored using SQLite. I have placed 2 menu buttons on the action bar one for going back and one deleting the task from list. When I click  the back button it works fine, but when I try to delete the task from list view it first asks whether the user wants to delete the task or not using AlertDialog.Builder then successfully toast the message but does not delete the task from list.

My code for the action bar menu button is given below. Please help me correct my code.I would really appreciate it.

Thank you in advance!

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_back:
                Intent openMainActivity = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(openMainActivity);
                return true;

            case R.id.action_discard:
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Second.this);
                builder
                        .setTitle(getString(R.string.delete_title))
                        .setMessage(getString(R.string.delete_message))
                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                        .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.yes), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                int id = getIntent().getExtras().getInt(getString(R.string.rodID));
                                db.delete(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, DbHelper.ID + "=" + id, null);
                                Toast.makeText(Second.this,"Task deleted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                db.close();
                                Intent openMainActivity = new Intent(Second.this, MainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(openMainActivity);
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.no), null)
                        .show();
                        return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
```

Comment: what is the error your are getting?add more detail of the problem.

Comment: I think your Id doesn't match to the database Id. Print your row id and check if it is correct.

Comment: @Adithya I am not getting any error thee application works fine. The only problem that occurs is that after I try to delete any task from the  list view, It doesnt delete. Toast message appears that that th task is deleted but the task still remains in the list view.

Comment: @MKY tried doing that It doesn't work for me

Comment: After deleting the data from database you need to query again and notify the adapter that data has been changed 
else close the app and reopen to see the effec

Comment: @MKY thank you so much. Your solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your Id doesn't match to the database Id. Print your row id and check if it is correct.

or

After deleting the data from database you need to query again and notify the adapter that data has been changed else close the app and reopen to see the effect.